# How to analyze learned parameters?

Tags: machine-learning, anova, interpretation

I have optimized a cost function by constrained minimization using cross validation starting from 200 or so initial points.  I have traced the optimization path of each chain, so I have many function evaluations.

I have noticed some things I expected to see, such as certain parameters that I figured would need to be low in order to reduce the value of the function being lower than average at optimal points in the cost function, etc., but I don't know the best way to formally test this.  I could comment on them in the discussion section of course, but I am hoping for a more thoughtful analysis.

I get significant results using ANOVA in R with the function evaluations as the outcome against the parameters. But I feel like this might have some problems since some of the parameters are correlated (a subset of them must sum to one) and are mostly not normally or log-normally distributed.

So, after parameter optimization for a machine learning problem, how are the parameters themselves analyzed?

Comment: Bit wonky. If you run smth like a regression of the parameters against the outcome you implicitly assume that there is a linear relationship between the variables. But if this were true, you wouldn't need to run the nonlinear minimisation in first place.

Comment: @appletree I agree, hence my hesitation to consider significant ANOVA results to be very meaningful.

Comment: I guess if you have some prior hypotheses like "feature 10 should have a lower-than-average value at the end of the optimisation" for many features you might consider something like a Wilcoxon rank-sum test: Take the set of features you expect to have large values and compare it to the set of features you expect to have low values, based on their final values at the end of  the iterations.

Comment: Interesting suggestion, thanks.  I will look into it.

Comment: Two things I don't yet get: how did you define (find?) your parameters and your cost function -- both have a huge impact on the outcome. And also, what do you mean by "parameter analysis", what do you want to do? What are you trying to explore in the first place? E.g. function regression?

Comment: @cherub Thanks for the question.  The parameters themselves are a mix of hyperparameters for functions which make up the cost function and the weights of those functions themselves.  I minimized a custom cost function suited for this problem using coordinate descent.  In general, I have noticed that certain parameters are low at minimal points in the function while others are high.  I am trying to test the idea that these values' lowness or highness are not random and indicate their importance in the underlying algorithm.

Comment: So far, I have decided to use a sign test among function evaluations near optimal values to show that parameters that are low or high there are significantly different from the mean from which they were sampled.  So if there were 4 parameters, I am testing that they are significantly different from 1/4 at lower/better values of the cost function evaluation.

Comment: I guess I picked a bad time to give a bounty (or more likely asked a poorly-worded question).  I think I have figured out a good solution and will post eventually.